# Is linkedList build on an Array

Tags: java, list

Where does Linked list store its data? is it using an Array or how does it work?

I know that it works with nodes but how does it actually store the nodes?

Comment: Why don't you look into source code and see it yourself? There is no array.

Comment: For OpenJDK: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html it is built by nodes.

Comment: In the instances of `Node` class. Why not to have a look at the sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `Node` links to (i.e. contains) the next `Node` in the sequence. The `LinkedList` class actually only contains the first `Node` in the list.

For example:
A linked list of `A`, `B`, `C` is as follows:

`LinkedList` contains a member variable `A`, `A` contains a member variable `B`, `B` contains a member variable `C`. `C` contains a `null` member variable.

`A` --> `B` --> `C` --> `null`

Should you Insert a new node, it would become...

`A` --> `B` --> `C` --> `D` --> `null`

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList does not use array to store data. It's a doubly-linked list, it stores its data in nodes

```
class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;
    Node<E> prev;
....
```

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList contains object Entry, which has current object and reference on next and previous objects. Then these next and previois objects also contains object Entry which has current object and reference on next and previous objects AND so on. 
Eventually you have sorta chain of object which linked each other.

This is inner class Entry in LinkedList:

```
private static class Entry<E> {
    E element;
    Entry<E> next;
    Entry<E> previous;
...
```

Where for example element is current object.

I hope I helped you.